# R: Storing counts of occurences of strings from one column in a new column

Tags: r

Say I have a dataframe, **df**, that looks like this:

```
              timestamp           residence
2014/01/29 10:46:46 PM EST        Virginia, USA
2014/01/29 10:51:01 PM EST        Maryland, USA
2014/01/29 10:54:08 PM EST   Massachusetts, USA
2014/01/29 10:55:00 PM EST         Indiana, USA
2014/01/29 11:02:31 PM EST        Michigan, USA
2014/01/29 11:19:42 PM EST        Virginia, USA
```

Now I want to take this and create a new dataframe, **df.count**, which contains one column listing every string found under in **df$residence** uniquely (once) and a second column listing counts for the number of occurrences of each string in df$residence. This is similar to

```
table(df$residence)
```

but the output format would instead look like:

```
         residence     count
     Virginia, USA     2
     Maryland, USA     1
Massachusetts, USA     1
      Indiana, USA     1
     Michigan, USA     1
```

Comment: Perhaps, the 'table' method of `as.data.frame` `as.data.frame(table(df$residence), responseName = "count")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution with `aggregate`:

```
setNames(aggregate(seq(nrow(df)) ~ residence,df, length), c("residence","count"))

           residence count
1       Indiana, USA     1
2      Maryland, USA     1
3 Massachusetts, USA     1
4      Michigan, USA     1
5      Virginia, USA     2
```

Comment: How would I go about this in such a way that I could still treat column "count" as numeric and perform functions like sum over it?

Comment: @soosus In the returned data frame, `count` *is* a numeric variable.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting errors saying I can't sum because it's a factor.

Comment: @soosus What function did you apply to the new data frame?

Comment: > sum(df.count$residence). The error I get is "Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L,  : 
  sum not meaningful for factors"

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could use `table` to build this new data frame:

```
tab <- table(df$residence)
data.frame(residence=names(tab), count=as.vector(tab))
#            residence count
# 1       Indiana, USA     1
# 2      Maryland, USA     1
# 3 Massachusetts, USA     1
# 4      Michigan, USA     1
# 5      Virginia, USA     2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay with `residence` as the names only:

```
with(df, data.frame(count=tapply(residence, residence, length)))
```

If you want an actual column with `residence`:

```
with(df, {
  summ <-tapply(residence, residence, length)
  data.frame(residence=names(summ), count=summ)
} )
```